# Multiple Virtual Hosts not working

Tags: apache, laravel, virtualhost, centos7

I am trying to set up two virtual hosts for one IP address say xxx.yy.xxx.yyy
I have my files on /var/www/html/folder1 and /var/www/html/folder2

I am adding VH like :
    
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/folder1
      ServerName xxx.yy.xxx.yyy/folder1
      
        AllowOverride All
      
    
    
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/folder12
      ServerName xxx.yy.xxx.yyy/folder2
      
        AllowOverride All

As I am new on CentOS7 Apache, can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Dude, you'd really ask this question in ServerFault

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if I can be helpful but I locally configure so apace to have multiple domains

```
<VirtualHost q4y.aurecchia.dev:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\QuestManager\AurQuest4You\public"
  ServerAdmin q4y.aurecchia.dev
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\QuestManager\AurQuest4You">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost csm.aurecchia.loc:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\CSM TEST\Aur_CSM\public"
  ServerAdmin csm.aurecchia.loc
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\CSM TEST\Aur_CSM">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```